# Understanding the sequence of operations when using ES6 Promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Take a look at this sample JavaScript code that uses Promises:

```
const promiseGen = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reject('something')
    })
}

promiseGen().catch(err => console.log(err))
console.log('after promiseGen')
```

I would have expected the output to be:

```
something
after promiseGen
```

But instead, it is

```
after promiseGen
something
```

Can someone explain why this is happening? Since I'm creating the promise first, which in turn calls `reject`, shouldn't `something` be printed first? Is the promise run on a separate thread such that the order of operations is not guaranteed?

Comment: Why did you expect that output? The *whole point* of promises is that they are resolved (or rejected) asynchronously, that's why you have to provide a callback rather than simply assigning the result.

Comment: That is because I was unaware that Promises always resolve after the sync code, as Thomas mentioned. I am a new JavaScript developer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Promise is always async *(even if ou resolve it immediately)*, and will therefore always resolve after the sync code.

Answer (score 0):

The specification of `Promises` require that even if they are doing nothing async they should behave in async manner for uniformity. So here, the then/catch method of the promise will get called on the next event loop check, which will happen when the call stack gets empty, which will become empty only after the execution of the last console.log() statement. Hence the results.